# Heating air inside a drum to raise pressure

Tags: pressure, air

Hi and thanks for adding me.
I have a complicated question!
I hope it's not too complicated for someone out there to help me!
So here's the situation.
I work in pharma and we supply drums to customers who have powders that need to be sealed in airtight conditions.  So I need to test the integrity of seals on stainless steel drums.
It's been suggested that to test I need to heat the air inside a 200L Stainless Steel drum to raise the pressure inside by 50mb.  The drum is completely open topped and on that open top has a flat lid and silicon O ring seal clamped into place.  If I could heat the drum and raise the pressure inside to 50mb then I could invert the drum and put the lid and seal area into a vat of water.  Air bubbles would then show me if there was a leak on the seal.  I need to test the Drum, Lid, Seal and clamp as a unit so I can't substitute ANY of the parts and there are no openings in the drum at all.  The plan would be to heat the drum using a band heater designed for oil drums.
Can anyone tell me how many degrees I would have to raise the temperature of the air inside the drum to increase the pressure by 50mb?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay-Lussac%27s_law 50 millibars doesn't sound like much...

Answer (score 1):

The required pressure increase is modest, so a lot of extra equipment is not needed.  The following assumptions are made:

The atmospheric pressure at your location is 1.01325 bar (sea level), which is denoted as $P_1$

The drum pressure must be 50 millibar above this, or 1.06325 bar, which is denoted as $P_2$

The ambient temperature of the room in which the pressure test will be conducted is 25 deg C (aka 298 K), which is denoted as $T_1$

Using the ideal gas law and the pressure ratio of $\frac{P_2}{P_1}$, the following equations result:

$\frac{P_2}{P_1}=\frac{T_2}{T_1}$

$T_2=\frac{P_2}{P_1}T_1$

$T_2=\frac{1.06325 bar}{1.01325 bar}298 K = 312 K = $ 39.7 degrees C

This means that you can close and seal your test container with 25 degree C air, submerge that container in a water bath that is heated to 39.7 deg C, wait long enough for the container to reach thermal equilibrium, and watch for air bubbles escaping as the container heats up.  Naturally, if any above assumptions are incorrect, you need to use the same method to calculate the proper bath temperature for your container.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you are performing a Sample Test, i.e. testing a barrel + lid combo without any product inside, and not intended for shipping.

I strongly recommend making a custom lid with a feedthru for both an air hose and a manometer.  Pump the pressure up to your desired point,close the input valve, and record the internal pressure for a designated period of time. Observe the change in pressure, if any.   Make sure the room temperature doesn't change during the test.